# Prevent users from viewing var/www/html back end files

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I saw several queries on how setting `var/www/html` permission. But I couldn't figure out my problem. I made a biological web tool for which I am the only maintainer and users can get data by submitting buttons and check-boxes. The site is developed using `php` (files and folders are stored inside `/var/www/html` folder) and accessible using  `http://163.xxx.xxx.xxx/tools/index.php`. However, if I just give the IP address only (ie,`http://163.xxx.xxx.xxx`), entire files and folders and displayed and can be viewed by any user.

I tried to changed the `chmod` of `/var/www/html` files to `755` and some others following some posts. But still every files can be viewed if `IP` address is given in url . How can I prevent others from viewing the back end files?

Am working on `Ubunu 14.04 LTS`

(I am really sorry for not asking the question technically because of my limited knowledge in this filed.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But  I am not still successful. I did follwoing things 1. created .htaccess file in var/www/html with Options All -Indexes.  Since its not working, I got another link saying to change AllowOverride All from AllowOverride None in apache conf file. Its also not working. I think .htaccess file is not recognized. Am I doing anything wrong here? Could you please comment on this. @muru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the directory listing in my Ubuntu 14.04 by following editing,

In the apache2.conf file, under

```
 <Directory /var/www/>,
```

there is a line 'Options Indexes FollowSymLinks'. Just delete the word "Indexes" and save the file. Restart the apache to take effect of the change.